# I2C ideal pull-up resistor calculation

Tags: i2c, pullup

As part of a test i was given the following question:
[image]

[image]

My attempt gave an incorrect answer. The "correct" answer is 1000 ohm but i am having trouble figuring out why. My interpretation; min value is:
$$
R_p = (V_{dd}-V_{OL})/I_{max} = 9.67 ohm
$$
$$
R_p = (3.3-0.4)/0.3 = 9.67 ohm
$$
This will give the fastest rise time but max current, question asks to minimise current so i should aim for the slowest allowable rise time. 
$$
T = 1/f = 1/100k = 10us
$$
minimum hold time is the minimum time during a period that the signal must be held high to correctly trigger the logic level. Therefore \$t_2\$ from the graph is:
$$
t_2 = T - t_{hold} = 10us - 300ns = 9.7us
$$
using the value given in the graph for logical high threshold:
$$
V_{IH} = 0.8V_{dd} = 0.8*3.3 = 2.64V
$$
substituting these values into the given equation to find R
$$
v(t) = V_{dd}(1-e^{-t/RC})
$$
$$
2.64 = 3.3(1-e^{-9.7u/R(200p)})
$$
$$
R = 30.13k
$$
closest E24 value being 30k (rounded down as 30.13k is the maximum) This is a great deal different from their answer of 1k, my question is where have i gone wrong? i feel like i have misintepretted the hold time or need to use the \$V_{IL}\$ value somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold time is the amount of time for which the signal must be stable **after** the clock edge. When the signal is low and starts rising on a clock edge it must not cross VIL for 300ns. You have
$$0.8 = e^{-300ns/(200pF R)}$$

However, that still does not give you the correct answer. I had a look at the I2C specification [here](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf). Interestingly, 300ns only appears as the rise time requirement when you are in fast mode, which is the mode for 400kbps. The time it takes for the signal to rise to VIH is:
$$0.2 = e^{-300ns/(200pF R)}$$
Solving for R
$$R = \frac{-1}{\ln 0.2} \times 300ns / 200pF\approx 932 \Omega$$

Comment: sorry what you have said does not quite match up. are you using the same formula as shown in the graph? the (1-e) has just become e? substituting your value of 932 @ t = 300ns gives 0.8Vdd ie VIH, but you have said that is when it should cross VIL?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited my answer.

Comment: okay i think im starting to understand thankyou. Is the equation given in my graph a valid one then? because you have stated that to obtain a hold time of 300ns, the signal should not cross VIL for 300ns. however when i use a value of 932ohm @ t=300ns, the equation puts the signal at VIH not VIL meaning the signal was not stable by your definition over the full 300ns? or is it a case of in fast mode rise time = hold time?

Comment: The equation in the graph is correct. It is the charging of an RC circuit. The only way I can think of to get the 1k answer you are after is to interpret the 300ns as the rise time requirement for the bus i.e. The time required for the signal to rise from 0 to VIH, which is what the I2C specification would suggest as well.

Comment: well unfortunately these tests have a track record of including mistakes so its possible it was meant to say rise instead of hold in the question. thank you for clearing this all up for me